Is there any option to get "to-many" relation objects while saving "parent" object?
I have three models
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    ... # other fields
    
    def _get_childs(self):
        first_childs = [f'{child.name}' for child in self.one_childs.all()]
        second_childs = [f'{child.name}' for child in self.two_childs.all()]
        return [first_childs + second_childs]
        
    @classmethod
    def get_config(cls) -> str:

        try:
            instance = cls.objects.get()
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            return ''

        config = {}
        for child in instance._get_childs():
            config[child] = {
                'interval': 1000,
                ... # other fields
            }
        return json.dumps(config, indent=4)
            
        
    
class OneChild(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='one_childs')
    ... # other fields
    

class TwoChild(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='two_childs')
    ... # other fields

I need to write get_config result to file ('/tmp/config' as example) on Parent save. everything works fine, but i get previous relations childs, not new. i tried to use it in post_save signal for Parent model, but it is does not help.
there is a signal for example
@receiver(post_save, sender=Parent)
def update_config(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    config_json = instance.get_config()
    file_path = '/tmp/config.json'

    with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
        file.write(config_json)

when I save Parent all values become valid except child.name's
is there any option to achieve this?

What did you try with that model? Where is the code?
